# What does the $k$the order statistic mean?

Tags: estimators, order-statistics

I'm writing an implementation of the $Q_{n}$ estimator as proposed by [Rousseeuw and Croux](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1993.10476408), as an alternative to the Median Absolute Deviation.

The estimator statistic is defined as
$$Q_{n} = d \{\left| x_{i} - x_{j} \right| ; i < j \}_{(k)}$$
where $d$ is a constant factor and
$$k = \binom{n/2 + 1}{b}\approx\binom{n}{2}/4 $$
which means the $k$th order statistic of the $\binom{n}{2}$ interpoint.

I'm unsure what this notation means. The wikipedia article on [robust measures of scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_measures_of_scale#Absolute_pairwise_differences) seems to suggest this is simply a more precise way of saying the first quartile of $\{\left| x_{i} - x_{j} \right| ; i < j \}$.

Is this correct?

Otherwise, if I have a list of numbers, $X = \{x_i, ... x_{n}\}$ how can I find
$$X_{(k)}$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $X_{(k)}$ notation literally means to put your observations in order and take the one in position $k$ (numbering from 1, not 0 as is common in many areas of computer science).

Your $Q$ seems, then, to be calculated by taking a bunch of distances between observations, ordering those distances, and taking the k$^{th}$-largest distance. The $i<j$ condition keeps you from finding distances from a point to itself ($0$ in any metric space) or from finding distances from $a$ to $b$ and then again from $b$ to $a$ (which are equal in any metric space).

(Note that your absolute value distance between observations  certainly qualifies your work as being in a metric space.)